# PHP dynamically build table row

Tags: php, html-table

EDIT:  I call the function `writecol()` further down the page inside `<table></table>` tags.

Example of data in trxtt.txt:

> South East asia,2222,code1
>
> winter break,3333,code2

I am fairly new to php.   I am trying to dynamically build table rows based off the variables read from an array.  When I call this function I do not receive and error message, but nothing happens.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
$x = file_get_contents('textt.txt');
$y = explode("\r\n", $x);

function writecol(){
    foreach ($y as $value) {
        $z = explode(",", $value);
        echo "<tr class='visible'><td class='underlinecenter'>" . $z[0] . "</td> <td></td> <td colspan='3' class='underlinecenter'>" . $z[1] . "</td><td></td><td colspan='3' class='underlinecenter'>" . $z[2] . "</td></tr>";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please give some sample data of `textt.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to be calling the function, nor is your function ready to receive the variable with data.

after $y = explode.... insert:
`writecol($y);`

Then replace `function writecol(){` with

`function writecol($y){`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the `writecol()` function

Answer (score 0):

Well...you never actually call the function. Therefore PHP just doesn't know that you intend it to use the function on the array you created. Additionally, you should add a parameter to your function, because from within `writecol()` your variable `$y` will not be visible.

Try it like this:

```
$y = explode(...);
function writecol($array) {
    foreach ($array as $value) { // your code }
}
writecol($y);
```

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you have these on (put them at the top under the php tag) for testing so you can see errors

```
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
```

Beyond errors, you aren't calling the function. change your function and add a call:

```
function writecol($y){ # <-- pass a variable and call it $y
    foreach ($y as $value) {
        $z = explode(",", $value);

        echo "<tr class='visible'><td class='underlinecenter'>" . $z[0] . "</td> <td></td> <td colspan='3' class='underlinecenter'>" . $z[1] . "</td><td></td><td colspan='3' class='underlinecenter'>" . $z[2] . "</td></tr>";
    }   
}
writecol($y); #<-- function call sending the variable $y
```